# Blender 2.80, Face area info

Tags: 3d-view, interface, faces

In blender 2.79 there was option of showing face area in properties menu, but in blender 2.8 I can't find it. Is there a way to show it in 2.8 version?

[image: face area display setting]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Face area is an overlay.
In the 3D view header, while a mesh is in *Edit Mode*, open the overlays popover and tick *Face Area* towards the bottom.

[image]